# Android SQLite issue, column not found

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working a poll portion of an app for work and I keep getting an exception saying that my answer 2 is not found when inserting values into the database.

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPoll SET Question='Who is more awesome?' WHERE rowid=1;");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPoll SET Answer1='Dan' WHERE rowid=1;");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPoll SET Answer2='Peet' WHERE rowid=1;");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPoll SET Answer3='Jordan' WHERE rowid=1;");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPoll SET Answer4='Spencer' WHERE rowid=1;");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPoll SET result1=0 WHERE rowid=1;");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPoll SET result2=0 WHERE rowid=1;");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPoll SET result3=0 WHERE rowid=1;");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPoll SET result4=0 WHERE rowid=1;");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE tblPoll SET resultTotal=0 WHERE rowid=1;");
```

This is my code to insert the items into the row, and it works for each of the answers(the members of the team), except for Peet. I've put Peet first, last, and as the second one, and he is the only one that breaks it.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "CREATE TABLE tblPoll (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
    "Question TEXT, Answer1 TEXT, Result1 NUMERIC, " +
    "Answer2 TEXT, Result2 NUMERIC, Answer3 TEXT, " +
    "Result3 NUMERIC, Answer4 TEXT, Result4 NUMERIC, " +
    "ResultTotal NUMERIC);";
```

This is my insert code to make the table.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

@2red13
I ran it like you had(with all the fields filled out properly, and it is still messing up on Answer2.

New code:

```
ContentValues werte = new ContentValues();  
    werte.put("Answer1", "Dan");
    werte.put("Answer2", "Peet");
    werte.put("Answer3", "Jordan");
    werte.put("Answer4", "Spencer");
    werte.put("Result1", 0);
    werte.put("Result2", 0);
    werte.put("Result3", 0);
    werte.put("Result4", 0);
    werte.put("ResultTotal", 0);
    db.update("tblPoll", werte,"rowid=1",null);
```

Comment: As a side note, can you guarantee you'll never need a fifth answer?

Comment: Are you sure the row with rowid = 1 exists? You are doing update not insert, so it won't get created if it's not already there. Also, you can set all fields in the same UPDATE or INSERT statement, google for some sql syntax :)

Comment: Maybe Peet is not that awesome...

Comment: @yock Its just a prototype for the app we're submitting to a client, so at this time, yes, I can. @Torp rowid=1 does exist. It is putting answer1,3,4 and result1,2,3,4,Total all in. It just breaks on answer2

Comment: I guess that all columns already have a value? Are you able to do a query and grab the column "Answer2" and print the results?

Comment: @pecka85 Nope, None of the columns are set up with an initial value. They are all null at the time of creation.

Comment: @Spencer Cole I can't see any reason why you should use `UPDATE` instead `INSERT`..? Anyway, can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: I run the code without error, but changed rowid to id (your autoincrement column). Can't see any problems, sorry

Comment: @Spencer Cole Did you figure it out? Have you tried to make the database again from scratch (that is, "Clear data" in "Manage applications", not to redefine the code)? Seems that there might have been an error at creation. You could also `ALTER` the table to make the column, but I would suggest to try making it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havn't any Idea whi Peet schoud fail, but the way you perform the updates is alittle bit slow, try:

```
ContentValues werte = new ContentValues();  
werte.put("Answer1", "Dan");
....
werte.put("resultTotal", 0);
db.update("tblPoll", werte,"rowid=1",null);
```

Maybe it solves the Peet Problem too ^^